# How to stop multiple ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
<button id="getInfo">Get information</button>
<div id="infoResponse"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('getInfo').addEventListener('click', function(){
    getInfo();
}, false);

function getInfo() {
    var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('infoResponse').innerHTML = xml.responseText;
        }
    };

    xml.open('GET', 'test.php', true);
    xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xml.send(null);
}
</script>
```

How do you stop the request to run again if the user is clicking the button more times? I would like to achieve something similar to jQuery one() event function

Thank you

Comment: You can abort the request, but once that request gets to the server there's no way to "stop" it

Comment: To replicate .one(), you would simply unbind the event inside the event handler.

Comment: Can can disable the button with javascript after it is clicked

Comment: couldn't you just set a flag and not send after the first time?

Answer (score 0):

One click callback could know about another click callback by setting a state somewhere.

If you have a spinning loader, you could look for that, so if `$('.spinner').length > 0` then you do not proceed in making the XHR request inside `.getInfo()`.

You could also unbind and rebind the event listener. Onclick, unbind itself, and on the success callback of the XHR, rebind the click handler.

Two strategies among many. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the solutions I have come with is this thanks to @KevinB

```
**document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', getInfo);**

**function getInfo(e) {**
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

**e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);**

xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xml.readyState == 4 && xml.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('infoResponse').innerHTML = xml.responseText;
    }
};

xml.open('GET', 'test.php', true);
xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xml.send(null);
```

}